# Android: using a background png image

Tags: android, xml, image

I am looking for the optimal way to use a .png image as the background for my app's main activity screen. I want to be able to fit properly on as many devices as possible.

What I have works, what I want to know is what best practices are for portability.

Here is the code I am using in my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_background"
    android:padding="25dp"
    >

...other stuff like a few buttons that go on top of background
```

Currently the file "main_background.png" is a 800px by 600px image. I notice on my phone at least the horizontal dimension gets shrunken inwards distorting the image as such. Is there an ideal Width::Height ratio I could make my background image?

Thank you.

Comment: You could set the width to `match_parent` and then use `LayoutParams` to set the height to the value of the width...

Comment: Thanks, that's the kinda tip I was looking for. Feel free to post an answer with the XML code so I can accept =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you would do is set up your xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_background"
android:padding="25dp"
>
```

notice the lack of `layout_height`...

In your main Activity, you would find the view, and execute the following line:

```
myLinLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, myLinLayout.getWidth()));
```

where `myLinLayout` is the linear layout, and you follow the `LayoutParams` method:

```
setLayoutParams(int width, int height);
```